# How to conditional rename a file if length of file name exceeds a certain value?

Tags: batch-file, filenames, rename

I have to run a batch file everyday in a folder to remove time stamp from the file name. I have a batch file to trim last 9 characters from the file name whenever I run it.

If the filename is `**Current Enrolled Members East 2015-01-31-14-01-01**` and I run batch file today, it trims time stamp and the file name becomes `Current Enrolled Members East 2015-01-31`. But if I run batch file again then it trims the last nine characters again. I just want my batch file to trim the file name only when there is a time stamp in it. Everyday files with new dates and timestamp come into the folder. I have three kinds of filenames in the folder
'Current Enrolled Members East','Current Enrolled Members West' and 'Current Enrolled Members Middle'

In order not to rename a file if it doesn't have timestamp after date, I have used the below script. It doesn't work. Please advise.

Looking for 4th delimiter as '-' and if it exists then call rename else don't.

```
dir /b | find "xlsx" /i > temp.log
 set tempvar=
 for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=." /f %%A in (temp.log) do (
 for /f "tokens=4 delims=-" /f %%Z in (%%A) do

 rename_file.bat %%A %%B

 )

 del temp.log
```

rename_file.bat

```
set fName=%1
set extn=%2

 ren %fName%.%extn% %fName:~0,-9%.%extn%
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've given us initially no examples, any response will be a guess.

I'd try

```
if "%filename:~40%" neq "" call yourbatchfiletotrimthelast10charactersfromthefilename
```

---

Given your filename - you haven't told us whether the name is contained in a variable or a metavariable.

I'd conclude that your batch removes the last nine characters by assigning the name to an ordinary environment variable and removing the unwanted part, probably using delayed expansion. Without the code, it's a guess.

Given the format presented, I'd suggest gating the rename by using

```
for /f "tokens=4delims=-" %%z in ("!currentfilename!") do call yourrenamebatch
```

which will only execute the batch you mention if the contents of `currentfilename` contains at least 3 <kbd>-</kbd>.

Comment: Hello Sir - I have used your 4 delims idea and tried implementing it as a condition. I have updated my question with the code of two batch files I am using. Could you please correct me where is it going wrong? Thanks for all your advise.

Comment: I've assumed you have a secondary batchfile and re-edited your post to show this. It *is* possible to include this procedure as a subroutine if required. In each `for /f` of your main procedure, you've specified the `/f` twice - that will generate an error. Once ony, directly after the `for` keyword. The subroutine needs to be `call`ed from the main, using the `call` keyword I specified, otherwise execution id transferred to the subsidiary batch and not returned when that batch ends. Also as specified, the `call rename_...` **must** be on the same physical line as the **do** of the `for..%%Z`

Comment: Please describe what happens and what you expected to happen. "It doesn't work" is meaningless. If it **did** work, you would not be asking the question, would you?

Comment: Thanks for editing the question and a detailed response. It doesn't work is meant for the logic I made using your idea. So, I wrote that the logic I wrote doesn't work - meaning I assumed, after the first for /f, the next for /f would go and check the %%A generated in the first for /f for any 4th delimiter and then call the rename_file.bat. When I run the main batch file, nothing happens and it just ends. I understood its not the way to write after your response. sorry, I have no idea about bat coding and apologize for any confusion. Thank you!

Comment: So - overall, is your procedure now working as you want it? If not, please edit your question to include your lastest code and describe what the problem is with the output.

Answer (score 1):

As your file names are constant with the exception of time information at end, you can use a very simple batch file with just 4 lines:

```
@echo off
if exist "Current Enrolled Members East ????-??-??-??-??-??" ren "Current Enrolled Members East ????-??-??-??-??-??" "Current Enrolled Members East ????-??-??"
if exist "Current Enrolled Members West ????-??-??-??-??-??" ren "Current Enrolled Members West ????-??-??-??-??-??" "Current Enrolled Members West ????-??-??"
if exist "Current Enrolled Members Middle ????-??-??-??-??-??" ren "Current Enrolled Members Middle ????-??-??-??-??-??" "Current Enrolled Members Middle ????-??-??"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and modification to the question. appreciate it.

Comment: If I have three different file names in the folder like, Current Enrolled Members East,Current Enrolled Members West and Current Enrolled Members Middle, Could you help me please. Sorry I am very newbie to batch programming

Answer (score 1):

No batch file is needed - a single REN command is all that is required !

```
ren "* ????-??-??-??-??-??" "* ????-??-??"
```

See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) for an explanation as to why this works.

Note - it is possible the above could rename files it shouldn't. For example:

```
"some description abcd-ef-gh-ij-kl-m"  -->  "some description abcd-ef-gh"
```

Obviously, the above does not have a timestamp, yet it matches the REN source mask. But it is unlikely you have such names to worry about.

Just in case you have complications, You could add the 20 to the mask, and then it will be more precise and good for the rest of this century (though still not bullet proof):

```
ren "* 20??-??-??-??-??-??" "* ????-??-??"
```

Or you could get a copy of my [JREN.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) and be very precise with the mask via a regular expression:

```
jren "(.* 20\d\d-[01]\d-[0123]\d)-[012]\d-[012345]\d-[012345]\d" $1
```

Use `CALL JREN` if you put the command in a batch script.

[JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) is a hybrid JScript/batch script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.